# Distinction Between Resources in App & Android Class Library

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an Android App & Android Class Library. Both have Styles in the styles.xml files declared as:

```
<style name="BasicButton">
```

In the app I reference this Android Class Library. In the xml layout file I have the following code:

```
style="@style/BasicButton"
```

This code is using the style from the Android Class Library, even though I have not changed anything in the layout file. I would expect it to use the local style by default. But no matter which one is used by default, I cannot find any way to explicitly specify which one I want in the xml (what if I wanted to use one in one place & the other in another place?). I also noticed the following lines in the Resource.designer.cs file of the app:

```
global::XamarinAndroidAppExtras.Resource.Style.BasicButton = global::PointTracker.Resource.Style.BasicButton;
public const int BasicButton = 2131755235;
```

How do I make a distinction between resources in the app & library when using them in an xml layout in my app?

Comment: For example,LibraryA, ProjectA .When ProjectA references LibraryA, it will "Merge" resources in the sense of combining the resources you can access within ProjectA. This should merge into one Resource.designer.cs file that you use to then reference the respective style in your XML. Not find any way to distinguish.

Comment: You say "the respective style in your XML". However, I have 2 styles that I need to reference (one from the library & one from the app). I need a way to specify in my xml which one to use. What it seems to be doing during the merge is, if the app & library both have a Style with the same name, REPLACING the one from the app with the one from the library, therefore making the Style from the app unavailable. I have seen places that say to do one of the following:
style="@XamarinAndroidAppExtras:style/BasicButton"
style="@style/XamarinAndroidAppExtras.BasicButton"
But neither one worked.

Comment: If I have two styles name BasicButton in my project and class library, I can use style by `style="@style/BasicButton"`, it will give priority to using the style of current project. If your project don't have the style name BasicButton, just in class library, `style="@style/BasicButton"` will  works fine.